# Only True Pokemon Fans Will Be Able to Solve This!

Tags: rebus, knowledge

Can you guess what these popular Pokemon are??[image]

Comment: No offense, but those are some pretty generic, well-known Pokemons, all from GEN 1 that any Pokemon Go player would know. Maybe a little more variety?

Comment: I'm quite the opposite: +1 for using real pokemon, but I'm biased probably because these are the only ones I know. That said, 1 2 and 3 are all very common, but the variety from 4 and 5 was refreshing.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1

> Pikachu

2

> Bulbasaur

3

> Charizard

4

> Jiggly-Puff

5

> Magikarp

All feature early on in the franchise, (not much of a fan myself) but [the Bulbapedia list of Pokemon by National Pokedex Number](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_National_Pok%C3%A9dex_number) helped, especially with #2.

Comment: Congratulations, these are correct! :)

Comment: Oh very fast answer, even for such an easy riddle

Comment: Yes, I did not know it would be that easy to solve! Do you guys think I should do a harder one?

Comment: yes, maybe don't hint that they are Pokemon leave that as part of the puzzle.

Comment: Good idea, lol, but now you'll be expecting it!

Comment: wait a few weeks, I don't read here every day.

Comment: @MicCrozier Now it's a HNQ everybody will.

Comment: What does the image for "saur" show?

Comment: @Simon A czar (Nicholas II) is shown for the picture of saur. :)

Comment: @MicCrozier Thanks - that was driving me nuts. At first I thought it was King George V, so I now have a pokemon called Bulbageorge.

Comment: lol, must be from a new generation! xD

Answer (score 4):

> 1. Pikachu
>  2. Bulbasaur
>  3. Charizard
>  4 - ? -gleeblow
>  5. Magicarp

Comment: I am currently on my phone and cannot see what 4. is. Formatting of the answer is also a bit off

Comment: Number four is incorrect, but the rest are correct!

Comment: Gleeblow is my new favourite Pokemon.

Answer (score 2):

This was really fun, and made me join the site just to post my answer and a couple of questions about this!

1

> (PEAS - S) + CAH + CHOO = PEA-CAH-CHOO = Pikachu

2

> BULB + AH + ? = BULB-AH-? = Can only be Bulbasaur. But I don't understand the third part?

3

> (CHARCOAL - COAL) + (LIZARD - L) = CHAR-IZARD = Charizard

4

> ? + GLEE + PUFF/HUFF. Since there is no known PKMN ending in "huff", it must be Jigglypuff (JIG-GLEE-PUFF). But I still don't get the first part? Is it a jigsaw, meaning we should put "-SAW" in the rebus?

5

> MAGIC + (CARPET - ET) = MAGIC-CARP = Magikarp. This one was really clever!

Comment: I believe the guy in #2 is **Tsar** Nicholas II.

Comment: That's awesome, I'm glad you had fun! :D @Kidburla