# Pokémon, Gotta Guess Them All!

Tags: lateral-thinking, rebus, knowledge

Below are some "rebus" that lead to names of different Pokémons. However, here is the catch: The rebuses do not all explicitly lead to the name of Pokémons. The rebuses may be describing the Pokémon's physical looks, a signature ability/move, name, or type. It's YOUR job to figure it out! Think out side the box. Please explain thoroughly!!!!
[image]

Hint, hint!

> Remember, some rebuses may be describing a SIGNATURE MOVE/ABILITY.

Comment: Based upon @miccrozier's https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/61354/only-true-pokemon-fans-will-be-able-to-solve-this

Comment: No problem, it was a nice rebus, but I figured this was test to see which users are REAL Pokemon geeks like me :)

Comment: @North I think you should add the [tag:knowledge] tag as this puzzle does rely on some Pokémon knowledge/trivia.

Comment: For A people, think abilities. But because I'm evil, no HINT FOR C!!! Mwahahahahahahahaah

Comment: Aura sphere is by no means anything close to lucario’s signature move unless you’re thinking of super smash bros brawl

Comment: I am aware that Aura Sphere is not Lucario's signature move, however, this move is frequently associated with Lucario. Rebus B was a physical/type overview of Lucario. However, I realized that Cobalion (the only other fighting type Pokemon that also has a steel attribute) was blue. So I put a sphere representing Aura sphere, since Lucario can learn that move while Cobalion can't (plus its stats don't add up to give it a special move), but Aura Sphere (thanks to Brawl) has made Aura Sphere more closely related to Lucario.

Comment: @North but this makes your hint hint rather misleading.

Comment: I'm sorry if my hint was misleading, but that was posted after couple ones were solved. It didnt apply to Lucario, but may apply to others

Comment: For C: We may be looking at the move 'dragon claw', with the claw in center of the image.

Comment: Btw, why accept a partial solution instead of full one?

Comment: Well, actually, the "full" answer was contributed by multiple people. C was the hardest to solve, so I wanted to be fair.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Partial Answer for C:

> A reverse Google image of the 1st picture tells me it is the **Judgment** Dragon from Yu-Gi-Oh.
>  Judgment is the signature move of  **Arceus** .
>  Moreover, Arceus is the master of the three  **Lake**  guardians.

Comment: This has to be right. It's too coincidental for it not to be.

Comment: Yes yes yes yes yes YOU ARE RIGHT!!!!!!

Answer (score 23):

Team Effort:

Answer for A (from [Robotnik](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61443/46176))

> (A.) Aegislash - has a stance change ability (which is evident from the diagram)

Answer for B (from [Mic Croizer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61424/46176))

> (B.) Lucario - since Lucario is a fighting/steel type and is blue, plus has a commonly associated move called Aura Sphere

Answer for C (from [Florian Bourse](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61459/46176))

> (C.) Arceus - since the dragon is called the Judgement dragon from Yu-gi-oh and Arceus's signature move is Judgement, plus Arceus is the trio master of the lake guardians.

Answer for D (from [Quantum Twinkle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61423/46176))

> (D.) Lunatone - Because it's in the shape of the moon, and looks like a rock.

Answer for E (from Tarius (me)):

> (E.) Leafeon - which splits into a leaf and eon (representing a large number)

Comment: Correct! Nice job. +1

Comment: Note: I figured out Lucario, Lunatone and Leafeon by myself, but had to go for help for the other two.

Comment: Team effort....community post?

Comment: Btw I out rocks because Lunatone is also a rock type pokemon

Comment: @PaigeMeinke Sorted :D

Comment: More specifically for E, aeon means a billion years in archaeology

Answer (score 7):

Partial answer:

A

> Maybe Charjabug, because this is the only Pokemon with the battery ability(hitting something can be battery).

B

> Lucario (From Mic Crozier)

C

> Maybe a Pokemon that knows Draco Meteor because it is a dragon with a lake(crater/meteor lake) So maybe

D

> Lunatone. Because it is in the shape of a moon and it is rock looking and rock type?

E

> Leafeon (From Tarius)

Comment: Will you explain why your answer is correct rather other possible answers?

Comment: Correct, +1 I had to put a rock so people dont think its Solgalia

Comment: E is incorrect, I'm afraid.

Comment: A is incorrect, you are thinking the wrong way! C is... well it's not INCORRECT (I mean you're just saying what the rebus looks like) but obviously incorrect.

Comment: Look ti the comments for hints

Comment: A is still incorrect, C is not even close.

Answer (score 7):

Partial:

> B) Poliwrath - blue fighting sphere - typing (water/fighting) and appearance
>  C) (Red) Gyarados - Dragon in the lake - plot point in gen II
>  D) Lunatone - moon and stone

Updated:

> A) Gurdurr - fights with a single steel beam
>  E) Chicorita?

Comment: I really like Poliwrath for B

Comment: A and E is both incorrect.

Comment: B and C are also incorrect

Comment: Oh well... I was hoping that at least Poliwrath was correct :(

Answer (score 7):

#### A

> **Aegislash** - Stance Change ability (Arrows show swapping between a defensive and offensive stance)

#### C (Incorrect but left for posterity)

> **Lugia** - Dinosaur/Dragon/Bird-like, known as the 'Guardian of the Seas'. In fact, the line in between the pictures makes it look like it's "Lugia OVER the Seas'

The other ones have been solved by other people, see [Tarius' answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/61431/46176) for the final results.

Comment: Yes! A is correct! C is incorrect, nice guess though

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I have so far:

B:

> (B.) Is it Lucario? It is blue, fighting, steel, and its first move can be "aura sphere"

D:

> (D.) Lunatone (Quantumtwinkie found this answer)

Comment: All FINAL answers are names of Pokémons.

Comment: Ohhh, okay, I will try and fix this!

Comment: Now B is correct. Good job!

Comment: Look to the comments for hints

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer:

A.

> sawk, who is a humanoid martial artist

B.

> A steel + fighting + blue pokemon. Lucario, where the sphere is https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Lucarionite

C.

> Probably a water/ice dragon type pokemon. I want to say gyrados, but your other choices lead me to newer pokemon I am not used to.

D.

> Lunatone (From Quantumtwinkie's answer)

E.

> Leafeon (Tarius’ Answer)

Comment: @North i was confident about e too.

Comment: B is close. Think about the sphere, too.

Comment: A is incorrect, c is incorrect, and E is incorrect

Answer (score 6):

Edit: Another guess

**A**

> **Aegislash**
>  The image shows a person with different stances, with specifically arrows going to 1->2->3. This makes me think the ability is *Stance change*, the signature ability of *Aegislash*.
>
>  As a bonus, the stance 1 & 3 is similar and look like a ready-to-attack stance, while 2 looks more defensive. Fits with how aegislashes switch between an offensive and defensive form with stance change.

**C**

> **Giratina**
>  First image is a dragon, and the second is a calm lake with a perfect reflection in it. A vertically inverted version of reality, so to speak.
>
>  *Giratina* is a legendary dragon type who reigns over the distortion/reverse world, an inverted dimension [which is closely connected to reflections and mirrors and pools of water](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Giratina_(Pok%C3%A9mon)).

Old answer:
<s>For C, though it's a bit of a stretch -</s>

> <s>Hydreigon, the only *dragon* type found in the *Clear Lake* dungeon in Pokemon Super Mystery Dungeon?</s>

Comment: No Im sorry its incorrect

Comment: Edited my answer. Quite sure of this one now :)

Answer (score 5):

Looks like only **C** needs answering:

> My guess is Articuno. The "dragon" looks like articuno (despite articuno not being a dragon type at all). But my real reason is because the second picture displays a *reflect*ion. The only pokemon that resembles a dragon and learns Reflect is Articuno. No dragon pokemon learn reflect other than through TM usage.

Answer (score 4):

A guess for A:

> Long Reach ability - Decidueye, since the staff gives a longer reach.

More guesses:

> Schooling ability - Wishiwashi, since he is training

Less plausible guess:

> Stamina ability - Mudscale, he is training for a long time

Comment: Sorry, none of the above.

Comment: The arrows are VERY important to the rebus.

Answer (score 4):

A:

> **Farfetch'd**. There's and item called Stick that only he can make use of. This is ignoring that hint you gave about abilities. With regards to your hint, the only ability I could think of was Sticky Hold (Get it? 'cause he's holding a stick) which isn't unique to a single pokemon.

C:

> **Rayquaza**. Shows a dragon over some place. I assume this refers to Dragon Ascent which is Rayquaza's signature move.

C (second answer):

> **Giratina**. The image below might be referring to the reflection on the water which leads me to think Reverse World i.e. Giratina.

Comment: I was thinking this for C, but also since that area looks something like Sootopolis, and given the events of Pokemon Emerald, I'd say this is evidence in it's favor.

Comment: Im sorry but incorrect

Comment: @North Edited in a second attempt at C.

Answer (score 4):

### Partial Answer

**C:**

> **Dragonite** A Dragon/Flying type. Closely tied with water and the sea (See Pokedex entries). Previous evolutions are blue-ish and can be caught in the water.

Comment: Im sorry, incorrect

Answer (score 4):

A:

> My guess is **Hitmontop**. Because of the turn or spin in the fighting stance I would think of a fighting type pokemon, maybe a rapid spin user and most of all the constant spinning motion of Hitmontop.

C:

> My first guess was **Palkia** just because it is a Water/Dragon Type.
> But then I thought it could be **Suicune**. Maybe it was the look of the creature in the picture, which made me think of one of the Legendary Beasts of Gen II. The water of the lake lead to a water type and in the original anime Ash met Suicune in the mist on a rock (hence mountains) of a lake, which also would fit for the shown pictures.

Answer (score 3):

For C:

> **Kyurem?** The first image represents a dragon and the second image denotes ice type...

Comment: Im sorry, incorrect